# Background SQLite task

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

In my app I need to read some data from the DB, so from whatever view I call another class containing all the DB related methods.

One of these methods does a query like this:

```
query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select * from orari where idutente=%d and date(orario)=date('now','localtime') order by orario", idUtente];
```

Then I'm building an object with the data from the query and add all the objects to a NSMutableArray that is returned by this method.

I'm omitting all the code of this method because I don't have problems with it and to keep the question clearer.

The table "orari" can have up to 18000 records and I've noticed that, just to execute that query on about 6000 records, the simulator needs about 4 to 6 seconds. So I thought about executing this method in a background queue, so that the main thread would not be blocked.

So I've tried with:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)NextGroup: (int)opt :(int)id {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
        ....
        here I execute my query, build the objects and add them all to my NSMutableArray
        ....
    });
    return myArray;
}
```

Now the problem is that return. If I put it inside the dispatch_async block, I get the error: "incompatible block pointer types passing 'NSMutableArray *(^)(void)' to parameter of type 'dispatch_block_t' (aka 'void (^)(void)')".

If I put it outside of the block, it will be empty.

How can I pass that NSMutableArray from the block to the method and then back to the view that called it?

Comment: Are you sure you wish to load all the data at once, main thread or background? Why not load just ids of rows and then gradually load batches when needed?

Comment: @LeoNatan I'm not loading all the data. Actually just few records get loaded in an object, but to choose those records I believe that the query has to go through the entire table.

Comment: The predicate you give it goes efficiently through the data. But when you do "select *", all record data is returned in the result. You could only request "_rowid_" and then based on these row ids, ask for the data in paging.

Comment: @LeoNatan I don't understand what you mean with "ask for the data in paging".

Comment: For example, as the user is scrolling the table, your could get 50 row every time. You have the row ids, you have their order, you just need to load the data. That way you only download a small portion (50) of the rows, and not all 18000.

Comment: @LeoNatan The problem is that I don't know where are the few (usually 5 to 10) rows I need to show to the user among the 18000 rows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39285/discussion-between-leo-natan-and-aleph72)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it. I'm just not sure if this is the best way to do it:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)NextGroup: (int)opt :(int)id {
__block NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
    ....
    here I execute my query, build the objects and add them all to my NSMutableArray
    ....
});
return myArray;
}
```

As you see, I've declared a block array outside the block and then I return it outside of it. It 's working, but is it the best way to do it?